# Assert that a combination of columns is unique (using `assertr`)

Tags: r, tidyverse, assert

I am looking for a "tidy" and concise way to make sure that a combination of columns is unique in a tibble using `assertr`.

So far, this is the best I could come up with:

```
PasteRows <- function(df) {
  apply(df, 1, paste, collapse = '')
}

tib <- tibble(a = c(1, 1, 3), b = c('a', 'b', 'b'))

tib %>%
  assert_rows(PasteRows, is_uniq, a, b)
```

... but I first have to define `PasteRows`. Also, I am not sure if `apply` has a performance penalty, because it converts the tibble into a matrix.

How can I improve and shorten this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`assertr` has the function `col_concat()` for this purpose.

```r
library(assertr)
library(tibble)

tib <- tibble(a = c(1, 1, 2), b = c('a', 'b', 'b'))

tib %>%
  assert_rows(col_concat, is_uniq, a, b)
```